# Mocking mongoose.save() to resolve `this` when calling `this.save()`

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mongoose, mocha.js, sinon

I'm trying to write unit tests for our application which uses mongoose. I have instance methods on a model which call `this.save()`

Eg.

```
MyModel.methods.update = function(data) {
    this.param = data
    this.save().then(updatedModel => {
        return updatedModel
    })
}
```

Is there a way to stub mongoose save to return the current `this` object?

Essentially, something like this:

`const save = sinon.stub(MyModel.prototype, 'save').resolves(this);`

but this is the referring to this in the instance method.

Hopefully what I described makes sense. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MDN `this` [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method):

> When a function is called as a method of an object, its `this` is set to the object the method is called on.

---

In your code sample `save` is always called as a method of a `MyModel` object so if you stub `save` by using `callsFake` and pass it a `function`, the value of `this` within that `function` will be the `MyModel` object that `save` was called on:

```js
// Returns a Promise that resolves to the MyModel object that save was called on
sinon.stub(MyModel.prototype, 'save').callsFake(function() { return Promise.resolve(this); });
```

---

Note that the above **will not** work if you use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Arrow_functions) since:

> In arrow functions, `this` retains the value of the enclosing lexical context's `this`.

```js
// Returns a Promise that resolves to whatever 'this' is right now
sinon.stub(MyModel.prototype, 'save').callsFake(() => Promise.resolve(this));
```

Comment: why not use `sinon.stub(MyModel.prototype, 'save').resolves(this)` ? Just curious if there is a preference of implementation

Comment: Damn, I'm relatively new to the javascript world, didn't realize `this` word work like that. Good to know!
Thanks